# Wie sagt man „to butcher a language“?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

*Ich tue mein Bestes, gutes Deutsch zu lernen, weil ich es nicht **verunstalten*** will.

Ich frage mich, ob ich in diesem Kontext auch das Verb ***vergewaltigen*** verwenden kann und warum.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass du auf das Wort "vergewaltigen" verzichten willst und anstelle "verunstalten" benutzt.

Comment: Idiomatischer ist die Verwendung eines Adjektivs statt eines Verbs. An Englishman *butchers* the German language. Ein Deutscher *spricht gebrochen* Englisch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Pons](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=butcher&l=deen&in=&lf=en) schlägt neben der Übersetzung *eine Sprache verunstalten* auch *verhunzen* für *to butcher* vor. Das Wort mag ich persönlich und würde in dem Kontext auch vorziehen.

*Vergewaltigen* wird von dict.cc in der Tat vorgeschlagen

> to butcher [fig.] [play, piece of music, language] – vergewaltigen

finde ich aber für deinen Beispielsatz etwas fehl am Platz. Das Wort wird in der Tat umgangssprachlich in der Form verwendet, aber gefällt mir zumindest hier nicht so gut.

Wiktionary definiert *vergewaltigen* wie folgt:

> übertragen: seine eigenen Interessen in Bezug auf etwas gewaltsam durchsetzen

Wenn du also bewusst die Sprache versuchst zu verunstalten/verhunzen und sie bewusst und absichtlich "falsch" sprichst, dann passen wohl alle diese Wörter, auch *vergewaltigen*.
Da dies aber eben nicht der Kern ist, sondern vielmehr das Gegenteil, würde ich bei *verunstalten* oder *verhunzen* bleiben, da beide Wörter meinem Verständnis nach die Absicht nicht implizieren.

> Ich gebe mein Bestes, gutes Deutsch zu sprechen, weil ich die Sprache nicht verhunzen/verunstalten will.

Answer (score 0):

Unser Deutschlehrer sagte: Ihr behandelt Sprache mit der Seele eines Metzgerhundes. Das englische to butcher ist aus dem Bereich Metzger, die Übersetzung vergewaltigen ist ein anderer Bereich, der Sinn ist eigentlich
"Sprache schlachten/abschlachten", aber das ist im Deutschen ungebräuchlich. Man muß sich also beim Übersetzen von englischen Verb lösen und frei nach Sinn übersetzen. Etwa: ohne das geringste Gefühl für Sprache".

Answer (score 0):

**Verunstalten** ist prima, aber auch **vergewaltigen** ist möglich. Letzteres ist aber ein sehr harter Begriff und wird in vielen Umgebungen als zu derb empfunden werden, weil er originär für Fälle sexueller Gewalt eingesetzt wird. Gerade das kann ihn aber andernorts gerade zum passenden machen.